# Yelp-Android InvalidSignature Exception

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2, yelp

I'm following the steps from the readme on GitHub to hit the Yelp Search API: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-android but it is yielding the following error and I'm not quite certain why my oauth_signature for the request is invalid:

```
com.yelp.clientlib.exception.exceptions.InvalidSignature
```

I'm not doing anything special outside of the suggested setup:

```
    YelpAPIFactory apiFactory = new YelpAPIFactory(Constants.YELP_CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.YELP_CONSUMER_SECRET, Constants.YELP_TOKEN, Constants.YELP_TOKEN_SECRET);
    YelpAPI yelpAPI = apiFactory.createAPI();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    // general params
    params.put("limit", "10");
    params.put("radius_filter","16094");
    params.put("cll", latitude + "," + longitude);

    final Call<SearchResponse> yelpDataCall = yelpAPI.search(getCity(latitude,longitude), params);

    yelpDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<SearchResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SearchResponse> call, Response<SearchResponse> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            SearchResponse yelpData = response.body();
            Timber.d("Response status code: " + statusCode + " - " + response.message());
            Timber.d("GET <-- " + call.request().url().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Timber.d("Response error code: " + t.toString());
            Timber.d("GET <-- " + call.request().url().toString());
        }
    });
```

The really strange thing is, this exact code worked just yesterday. I have tried setting up the call synchronously and well as asynchronously and both yield the same exception.